# Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell XPS L701X with GeForce GT 435M - Low Resolution

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, resolution, bumblebee

Moving from Ubuntu 12.x to 14.04 (clean install, not an upgrade) I've ran into trouble I've never had before.  Many times I've installed bumblebee with the proprietary nvidia drivers, but this time trouble started when I opened `nvidia-settings` ("NVIDIA X Server Settings") and discovered there was no longer an area to set my resolution. Instead, only sections for "Application Profile" and "nvidia-settings Configuration".  I can't find how to restore my resolution to 1600x900 from the the 1024x768 it seems to be stuck at.

There does seem to be a lot of information out there close to my problem, and I found some excellent post including [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers), but after two solid days of attempts, I can't seem to put the pieces together, and I'm not really getting anyway when it comes to even understanding my problem better.

I've tried the recommend nvidia-304, nvidia-current, and a number of drivers including 340 from Xorg Edgers.  I can get bumblebee to work (for example, I can run `optirun glxspheres64`) but nothing seems to give me my resolution back.  At this point, I'm not sure what would be the best details to provide, but I'm getting many messages I don't really know what to make of. I hope something here is a clue.

`lspci -vnn` shows me the following "Unknown header" message, any time after I've installed bumblebee:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106M [GeForce GT 435M] [10de:0dd3] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
```

In all cases, if I attempt to do anything with xrandr, I get:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

When I switch to another shell (ctl-alt-F1, etc), I'm constantly getting the following message:

```
intel ips 0000:00:1f.6 failed to disable graphis turbo
```

Running nvidia-settings, beside not showing me the options I expect, also says:

```
** (nvidia-settings:3545): WARNING **: PRIME: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/prime-supported" (No such file or directory)
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

Thanks in advanced for any tips!